# Find and prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n x^k$

Tags: limits, proof-writing

Find:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n x^k$$ Where x is a set of the complex numbers and $|x|<1$

Then prove the limit using $\epsilon$ and $N_0(\epsilon)$

I think the limit is either $0$ or $\frac{1}{1-x}$ but i'm not sure which. Given either I don't know how to do the proof

We also know $x$ is in the set of complex numbers

Comment: x is set of complex numbers?

Comment: Yeah, sorry forgot to mention that

Comment: You may already know that the (finite) sum is $\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$. That is a good place to start.

Comment: See [Geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).

Comment: Given any $\epsilon >0$ we have

$$\left|\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}-\frac{1}{1-x}\right|=\frac{\left|x\right|^{n+1}}{|1-x|}<\epsilon$$

whenever $n>-1+\frac{\log \epsilon +\log |1-x|}{\log |x|}$

Comment: So the limit is $\frac{1}{1-x}$?

Comment: Yes, the limit is $1/(1-x)$.  Shall I write a solution?

Comment: If you could that would be amazing, my understanding isn't quite there yet